# Linux kernel booting stops at Uncompressing Linux... Ok, booting the kernel

Tags: linux, embedded, bootloader, u-boot

I have a problem about porting kernel from old SH4 to new SH4. Please let me show the difference between them.

[Old SH4]
boot loader: redboot v2.0
kernel version: 2.4

[New SH4]
boot loader: u-boot v2009.03
kernel version: 2.6

In old SH4, a lot of source code is developed based on kernel 2.4, so porting kernel 2.4 to new SH4 looks easier than recompiling source codes in kernel 2.6. So I applied mkimage to the zImage which was developed for old SH4 as shown below.

```
mkimage -A sh -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x8c210000 -e 0x8c210000 -n 'Old kernel' -d zImage uImage
```

This image is loaded on new SH4 as shown below.

```
tftpboot 8c800000 uImage
cp.b $(fileaddr) a0100000 $(filesize)
bootm a0100000
```

However, booting stops after "Uncompressing Linux... Ok, booting the kernel" and hangs. I found that the infinite loop happens at the below lines on kernel/head.S, but I suppose these lines have no problem because kernel/head.S is not customized and it works on old SH4.

```
   !               Clear BSS area
   mov.l   3f, r1 ! __bss_start
   add     #4, r1
   mov.l   4f, r2 ! _end
   mov     #0, r0
9: cmp/hs　r2, r1
   bf/s    9b     ! while (r1 < r2)
   mov.l　 r0,@-r2
```

Thus, I guess this problem comes from environment difference between old and new SH4. In old SH4, I execute fconfig command and set variables as shown below.

```
Load Linux Kernel & File System: true
Linux Kernel Destination address: 0x8c210000
Linux Kernel Source address: 0x80140000
Linux Kernel Size: 0x100000
RAM disk Destination address: 0x8c360000
RAM disk Source address: 0x80140000
RAM disk Size: 0x400000
Modify Linux Kernel Parameter: true
Linux Kernel base address: 0x8c001000
Linux Kernel ENTRY address: 0x8c210000
Linux Kernel INITRD size: 0xc00000
Linux Kernel INITRD start address: 0x360000
Linux Kernel loader type: 1
Linux Kernel mount root read only: 1
Linux Kernel original root device: 0x100
Linux Kernel RAM disk flags: 0
Linux Kernel Enable Virtual Terminal Console: false
```

I think I can set these parameters on new SH4, though u-boot doesn't have fconfig command. But I couldn't find how to set the parameters Linux Kernel Source address and Linux kernel base address. Is this related to the hang problem? Or any advice about what I should check next will be helpful since I am new to Linux embedded system.

Thanks for your help.

[Edited]
Below infomation is added to show printenv result on u-boot.
bootcmd=icache on
bootm a0100000
bootdelay=2
baudrate=115200
netmask=255.255.255.0
ipaddr=192.168.1.2
serverip=192.168.1.1
gatewayip=0.0.0.0
bootargs=console=ttySC1,115200,N,8 mem=32M ether=8,0x1300,0,0,eth0 video=e1356fb:system:ms104sh4,display:crt,bpp:8,800x600@60
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial

Comment: if you have access to the preboot envirnoment, you can use the uboot `setenv` command to set those. See http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootEnvVariables

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop? What are the register values? The code you posted is clearing RAM area. If the kernel load address is incorrect you could be erasing the memory location where the code is running. I had a similar problem though on the PowerPC platform. My problem turned out to be incorrect base addresses in the Linux config file.

Comment: To J-16 SDiZ: Thanks for your comment. First I thought I could set LINUX base & source address via u-boot environmental variable, but found no variables for them. Maybe I have to set them in a different way not in env variables.

Comment: To sessyargc.jp: Thanks for your comment. It could be true that the address running is zero cleared dut to bad base address because I leave it default setting. I think I have to check again how I can set base address in SH4.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with SH4, but this has helped me in the past: http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxPostMortemAnalysis

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I checked log_buf address on new SH4, and found some errors. It says like "RedBoot partition parsing not available". Looks like the old SH4 kernel has an dependency on redboot, and I found it on drivers/mtd/maps. I don't know if this error is related to the hang, but this may be the place I have to deal with next as well as Linux base address setting.

Comment: And you actually should be able to edit the Linux base address that UBoot will use, try using the `printenv` command and look for the `bootcmd` parameter, it looks like this on one of my systems: `bootcmd=bootm fc080000 - fc060000`, the first argument to `bootm` is the address of the image, your `bootcmd` will look different. However, since you're getting a RedBoot error, the base address is probably not an issue :) If you run `printenv` and post the results, that might be somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is the printenv result. bootargs (and some ip related variables) is modified to make it the same as old SH4 environment.bootcmd=icache on ; bootm a0100000 bootdelay=2 baudrate=115200 netmask=255.255.255.0 ipaddr=192.168.1.2 serverip=192.168.1.1 gatewayip=0.0.0.0 bootargs=console=ttySC1,115200,N,8 mem=32M ether=8,0x1300,0,0,eth0 video=e1356fb:system:ms104sh4,display:crt,bpp:8,800x600@60 stdin=serial stdout=serial<br>stderr=serial

Comment: Great! You may want to put that in the original post so it's more readable. Back to your previous comment, "RedBoot partition parsing not available" is not the issue (at least not yet), I see that message in my system too. The problem it looks like you're having is that the kernel is not properly writing to the console. Check your "console=ttySC1,115200,N,8" argument to make sure it's correct, and check your kernel's console initialization code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, looks like ttySC1 is fine. For me embedded beginner, this problem may be difficult to finish by the deadline, so I decided to change whole new SH4 environment. I mean, I delete u-boot on new SH4 and install redboot on old SH4. I hope this could solve the problem. Anyway, thanks for your great advice and support!